# How does timestamp hashing work?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, public-key-encryption, sha256

Suppose you have an existing hash `g84t5tw73y487tb38wo4bq8o34q384o7nfw3q434hqa` which was created from the original string `dont downvote my stupid question`

Now I timestamp this hash like this (in JS/pseudo-code):

```
var hash = 'g84t5tw73y487tb38wo4bq8o34q384o7nfw3q434hqa';
var today= new Date(); // 2017-10-19

var timestamped = hash + today; 

var new_hash = SHA256(timestamped); 

// new_hash is 34t346tf3847tr8qrot3r8q248rtbrq4brtqti4t
```

If I wanted to verify my original string I can do:

```
var verified = goodHash('dont downvote my stupid question',hash); // true
```

If I wanted to verify the timestamped version I can do:

```
var original_hash = 'g84t5tw73y487tb38wo4bq8o34q384o7nfw3q434hqa';
var today = '2017-10-19';
var verified = goodHash(original_hash+today, timestamped_hash); // true
```

But if I tried to verify the original string against the timestamp, I CANT do:

```
var today = '2017-10-19';
var verified = goodHash('dont downvote my stupid question'+today, timestamped_hash); // FALSE
```

Now suppose this original string is hashed and timestamped over and over again for `n` iterations.

I would only ever be able to verify the `n-1th` timestamp, provided I have the `n-1th` hash.

But what if I have the original string `dont downvote my stupid question` and want to verify any `ith` timestamp, where `0 < i < n`.

Basically, I want to verify whether a string that only I should have knowledge of, has been timestamped with a given date, regardless of how many times it may have been timestamped *and* without increasing the length of the string (too much - although *any* increase in length would approach infinity as `n` grows).

Is this even possible? Can a hash even contain all this information?

Comment: My gut tells me that you have to know the original string and all the timestamps (up to the ith one) to generate the ith hash.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the mathematics involved here:

First, you have a input string `s` and a sequence `t` of timestamps. I will use `t[i]` to denote the `ith` timestamp. Your repeated hashing is a recurrence relation:

```
f(i) = hash(f(t[i-1]) + t[i])
```

Where `+` denotes string concatenation. Now we want to determine if there is a closed formula `F(x)` which will calculate the `ith` hash with less time-complexity than evaluating the recurrence relation `f(i)`.

One way to accomplish this is to find a string `x(i)` with the same hash as `f(t[i-1]) + t[i]`. For a good hashing algorithm, these collisions are exceedingly rare. My gut instinct is that finding such a string (other than `f(t[i-1]) + t[i]` itself) is more difficult than simply calculating directly from the recurrence relation.

Comment: hows this an answer to the question OP asked.

OP is asking, given `t[n]` and `s`  (the other timestamps `t[i] where 0 < i < n` are not known), Can  he verify the nth hash